# Login in CodeIgniter with password_verify

Tags: php, codeigniter, passwords

I'm trying to achieve to login implementation in CodeIgniter, I'm hashing password while registration like `password_hash($this->input->post('password'),PASSWORD_DEFAULT)` in my Controller and in the same Controller I'm trying to write a login method which is as followed :

```
public function loginValidation() {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
            // true
            $email  =   $this->input->post('email');
            $password   =   $this->input->post('password');

            // User Model Loaded in constructor
            if ($this->user->canLogin($email, $password)) {
                $session_data   =   array('email' => $email );
                $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
                redirect('profile/personal','Refresh');

            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Invalid Username or Password');
                //redirect('login','Refresh');

            }
        } else {
            // try again to login
            //redirect('login','Refresh');
        }
    }
```

My user Model function is

```
public function canLogin($email, $password) {
    $this->db->where('email',$email);
    $this->db->where('password',$password);
    $query  =   $this->db->get($this->tableName);

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I know I have to `password_verify($string,$hash)` at some point but I'm unable to figure out.

How do I validate the password against email and redirect to the desired view i.e. `personal/profile` and I'm making request via AJAX call.

Comment: You select the row from the DB based on the username (and not the password, because it is hashed), and then you check the stored password against the password that was entered by the user

Comment: Dont use the password in WHERE condition. Fetch the record and compare the hash form DB with password_verify

Comment: @AlonEitan can you please elaborate with an example or a snippet?

Comment: No, because I don't know the codeigniter framework, but instead of adding `$this->db->where('password',$password);` you remove that line, and then you fetch the row from the DB and you verify `$this->input->post('password')` against the password (From the DB)

Comment: @AlonEitan Fair enough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is fetch the record from the DB where only the email matches (assuming it is the Unique key). Then you compare the returned value using [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).
This is very rough and untested, but should give you an idea:

```
public function canLogin($email, $password) {
    $this->db->where('email',$email);
    // $this->db->where('password',$password);
    $query  =   $this->db->get($this->tableName);

    $row = $query->row();
    return $row ? password_verify($password, $row->password) : false;
}
```

Comment: so it should be `return password_verify($password,$query->password);` ?

Comment: it's `n` rows returned unless you know the DB has a unique index on email (which it should have), then it's 1 or 0 rows.

Comment: `return $row ? password_verify($password, $row->password) : false;`

Comment: Sure, it's basically what you had already just in a single line, you could also have done `if($row) return password_verify($password, $row->password);` and then after that `return false;`  same thing  (AKA single line if).

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix that's just beautiful